# Running local Moran's index in all fields automatically?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-statistics

I want to use the local Moran's I index in ArcGIS.

I have a table/layer with 50 columns.

Can I execute moran in all fields of this table automatically or do I have to run the tool 50 times?

Comment: manually since you need to confirm that all conditions are met before using the tool.  This is cross-posted on GeoNet under the same title https://geonet.esri.com/thread/173847

Comment: Please take @Dan Patterson's advice to heart. Applying Moran's-I across 50 variables , without testing assumptions, is just a bad idea. I would also wonder why you would want to even do this. How would results be interpreted? In regression equations you commonly look for autocorrelation on the left side (y) of the equation. This how one evaluates iid assumptions.